# ios UITextView not show text at right position

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `UITextView` named textSearch, first I assign a text "AAAAA" for it. It show at left align, no problem. But when I touch to edit textview, **it slide this text "AAAAA" to upper**, **so I just can see a lower half part of text**, it's an annoy bug. When I replace textview to textfield, it's OK, no problem!!! I build on phone 3GS and have this bug, but when build on iphone 4, it's Ok. What a strange bug!

Here my declaration for textview

```
textSearch = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, posY + 5, 245, 35)];

textSearch.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.9];

textSearch.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

textSearch.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

textSearch.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

textSearch.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

textSearch.delegate = self;

[[textSearch layer] setCornerRadius:5];

textSearch.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

textSearch.text = "AAAAA";

[titleTableView addSubview:textSearch];

[textSearch release];
```

I implement some delegate of `UITextViewDelegate`, but I'm sure not their false
Is any idea for my problem.

Comment: Hi,Did you find a solution ? I have the same kind of issue and i'm looking for a way to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn ah Sorry, I can not find reason for it as well as solution to fix it. I just replace by UITExtField. Hope you find solutions and please tell me if you do. Thanks